# Copied Drupal 8 to Live server now can't log in

Tags: 8

I built a simple Drupal 8 website on my DEV box and moved it to the LIVE server.

1. Copied the files on the DEV server into a tarball
2. Moved these file to the LIVE server (using scp).
3. Uncompressed web files into it's destination directory
   (/var/www/html/newsite)
4. Created the database, user and set permissions to match that on the
   DEV server
5. Backed up the MySQL Server database into a .sql file with mysqldump
6. Imported from the .sql file into the database of the same name
7. Made sure the APACHE settings pointed to the site's directory

When I navigate to the front page, it comes up.

- Images and page content displays
- Webform works and emails the account it is set for

BUT cannot navigate to any other page!

- /user = Page not found
- /[anything] = Page not found
- /?q=user = goes to the (front) page and the URL remains with the
- /?=[anything] = shows the front page with the URL remaining

Meaning I cannot log in or run (database) updates!

I've tried

- deleting the Sessions table in the database
- verify mod_rewrite is enabled in httpd (CentOS)
- verified the apache (httpd) config files match

Any help or ideas appreciated.

I don't think wiping out the website, install a Drupal site and then copy the files/database over the new one would fix anything.

Comment: Have you got a copy of the Drupal .htaccess file in the webroot?

Comment: Those are the exact symptoms of a missing/unprocessed .htaccess file

Comment: There is a .htaccess file in the webroot.  What am I looking for in the file?

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride All` in the vhost? If yes, is the `<Directory>` path that's under definitely correct?

Comment: Try truncating all the cache tables and running the 'update.php' file or using Drush (drush updb).

Answer (score 1):

Clive, you are correct.

Looking in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (Apache configuration file on RedHat based distributions such as CentOS) I added the directory and include the `AllowOverride All`.

Once I refreshed it works!  Thank you!